Show that any two embeddings $f, g : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ are homotopic through smooth embeddings.
This question is from a publicly available old qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I couldn't find anything in the several textbooks I was using for this problem, so I looked online and it appears that this problem mostly reduces to knot theory (a subject that wasn't explicitly mentioned in the reference material for the practice tests, and that I wasn't familar with.)


Show that any two embeddings $f, g : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ are homotopic through smooth embeddings.

Answer: The strategy is to unkot both embeddings in $\mathbb R^4$. If the images of both maps can be unkotted, then they are trivially isotopes of each other.
This step of the proof is mostly an informal restatement of the great proof found here. I studied the proof and rewrote it in my own words to try and grasp an intuition for the problem, but feel free to go read the original linked proof.
Denote the image of $f$ by $\left | f \right \rangle$
The span of all possible lines between any two points in $\left | f  \right \rangle$ is
homeomorphic to the span of all lines that run between any two points on the torus, that is $S^1 \times S^1 \times \mathbb R$. It can be seen intuitively (or more rigorously using Sard's theorem) that any point in $\mathbb R^3$ can be represented as a linear combination of these lines, but not every line through the origin in $\mathbb R^4$ can be represented this way. Then there is an additional basis in $\mathbb R^4$ we can choose for $\left | f \right \rangle$, which allows us to independently deform $\left | f \right \rangle$ homotopically to and from it's projection in $\mathbb R^3$ without having to cause new intersections.
$\left\{ h_t\right\}_t$ is our family of maps. Letting $h_1 \left | f \right \rangle $ = $\left | f \right  \rangle$ and $h_0 \left | f \right \rangle $ be it's projection onto $\mathbb R^3$, we can apply a bump function to any intersection in $h_0 \left | f \right \rangle $ that lifts a small neighborhood of $\left | f \right \rangle$ and allows us to isotope $\left | f \right \rangle$ to an unknot in $\mathbb R^4$. We can apply the same process to isotope $\left | g \right \rangle$ to an unknot in $\mathbb R^4$.
Two unknots in $\mathbb R^4$ are trivial isotopes of each other, so $f$ and $g$ must be isotopes.

(a) The unknotting part of the proof is mostly a restatement of another post on this website. However, the final step involves deducing that if the two images are isotopes, then the functions from matching domains must also be isotopes. Is this true?
As usual, if there's a bonus technique that's more efficient, let me know.
